# Are these two weeds both lambsquarter?

Tags: identification, weeds

These two western Idaho weeds look like lambsquarter to me. One of them is blunt, and the other one is pointy (and much more susceptible to leaf miners and some disease that wilts the shoots and leaves). Are they both lambsquarter? What are the variety names, if you can tell? Because of the immaturity of the weed in the second picture, you might be tempted to say it's bind weed or something (but it's not; it's not a vine; the growth habit is just like that of the blunt variety).

Blunt variety (picture 1):
[image: Blunt lambsquarter?]

Blunt variety (picture 2):
[image]

Pointed variety:
[image]

Comment: The pointed plant appears to have an arrowhead appearance to it, the way the back of the leaf extends behind the petiole. I've never seen that in a lambsquarter before, and I've seen a lot of them. The first is lambsquarter as you expected.

Answer (score 3):

The first two pictures ('blunt') appear to be lamb's quarters.
As for the "pointy" one, an identifying characteristic is the red or purple-ish stem and underside of leaves when the plant is young.

More details from the [Ontario (Canada) Agriculture Ministry](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/crops/facts/ontweeds/lambs_quarters.htm) guide to weeds:

> Stems & Roots: 20-200cm (8in.-6½ft) high, branched or unbranched,
>   smooth, green or with reddish or purplish lengthwise stripes and
>   ridges
>
> Leaves: First 2 or 4 true leaves apparently opposite (2 per node), but
>   all later leaves and branches distinctly alternate (1 per node);
>   leaves stalked, the blades 3-10cm (1-4in.) long, lance-shaped or more
>   often broadly triangular with irregular, usually shallow teeth; leaves
>   green or grayish due to a covering of a white mealiness or
>   powderiness, sometimes with reddish undersurface on young plants.